# converting selected document from DOCUMENT PICKER in react native to base64 using RNFetchBlob

Tags: react-native, base64, data-uri

I have some problem about my react native app. I would just like to ask if are there any ways that RNFetchBlob will accept a dataURI from documentPicker instead of a web URL? I just need to convert the selected file from document picker to base64. Could anyone help me?

```
RNFetchBlob.config({ fileCache: true })
.fetch("GET", 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf') // Replace the web URL to dataURI from documentPicker
   // the image is now dowloaded to device's storage
   .then(resp => {
      // the image path you can use it directly with Image component
      // return resp.readFile("base64");
      return resp.readFile("base64");
   }).then(base64Data => {
      console.log('base64Data', base64Data);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not particularly looking for base64 encoded but want to obtain the actual blob you can use fetch without going through base64 bridge

```
const fetchResponse = await fetch(at[i].uri);
const blob = await fetchResponse.blob();
```